# restrict the autocomplete search results to a user input.

Tags: input, autocomplete, restrict

I want to restrict the autocomplete search results to the areas and places of a specific city. Ex: user select his city in a first "autocomplete" and the the second "autocomplete" show airports of this input. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `onchange` attribute to the first select box which calls a function when user select a value.
2. The function should send an ajax request to the server.
3. in server side, query airports under the specific city and respond the details.

4.Again in client side, parse the response and suggest it.